# Calc =NOW() function returns ### instead of current time and date (maybe Arch locale)

Tags: linux, libreoffice, archlinux, libreoffice-calc

LibreOffice Calc.

[Img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kkZl7.png)

When I use the "=NOW()" function, it returns "###" instead of the current date and time.
I think the problem is probably in my Linux locale.
I'm using Arch.
What should I do to fix it?
I can provide more information, but what kind?

Note that the "=DATE()" function works correctly, so it's most likely a time issue on my machine.

Comment: Welcome! See first row in [**Error Codes Help**](https://help.libreoffice.org/latest/en-US/text/scalc/05/02140000.html?DbPAR=CALC#bm_id3146797): ***The cell is not wide enough to display the contents.***

Answer (score 1):

> The cell is not wide enough to display the contents.

If you make the column wider, the content will be revealed when there is enough visual space.

This is documented here:

https://help.libreoffice.org/latest/en-US/text/scalc/05/02140000.html?DbPAR=CALC#bm_id3146797